# Why is POINT() being stored as ??*??E@z?3M??Q? in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, gis, point

I don't understand why my `POINT` data type from MySQL GIS is being inserted as `??*??E@z?3M??Q?`.

My code is below. Any help would be extremely appreciated, I've spent quite a while tinkering around and reading the docs. Thank you in advance!

My query:

```
insert into locations values(null, POINT(43.005895, -71.013202), 'Car wash');
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
  location_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    coordinates point NOT NULL,
    name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (location_id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: How are you displaying the value?

Comment: just doing `select * from locations`, but I'm getting an eerie feeling that i'm supposed to use ST_X() and ST_Y(). But how would I go about getting each value that's stored in point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ST_AsText()` to convert the GIS data from the internal format to a WKT string:

```
SELECT location_id, ST_AsText(coordinates) as coordinates, name
FROM locations
```

Comment: Wowza, thank you so much, i'm about to bust out crying.

Comment: I don't mean to be a nuisance Barmar, but I was wondering if I could ask you two brief questions somehow. I'm kind of a novice at MySQL and was wondering if you'd take 5 minutes of your time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't make myself available for private consulting. I do this in my spare time when I feel like it.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: The "why" part of the answer is that `ST_AsText` takes the binary representation of the geometry (what you're seeing here), and returns a well-known text (WKT) string representation.